# Appcelerator Geolocation not working on Android

Tags: javascript, android, geolocation, titanium

The following code from a Titanium sample works fine on iPhone but not on Android. Can someone show me how this can be written so that it will work on Android 2.3.3 as well? The error does not show if I comment out 'Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition' and it's end tag.

```
if (!_bounty.captured) {
    var captureButton = Ti.UI.createButton({
        title:L('capture'),
        top:10,
        height:30,
        width:200
    });
    captureButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (Ti.Geolocation.locationServicesEnabled) {
            Ti.Geolocation.accuracy = Ti.Geolocation.ACCURACY_BEST;
            Ti.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {  //*causes error on Android*
                var lng = e.coords.longitude;
                var lat = e.coords.latitude;
                bh.db.bust(_bounty.id, lat, lng);

                bh.net.bustFugitive(Ti.Platform.id, function(_data) {
                    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                        message:_data.message
                    }).show();

                    //on android, give a bit of a delay before closing the window...
                    if (Ti.Platform.osname == 'android') {
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            win.close();
                        },2000);
                    }
                    else {
                        win.close();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
        else {
            Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                title:L('geo_error'), 
                message:L('geo_error_details')
            }).show();
        }
    });
    win.add(captureButton);
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is the error message?  Which Ti version?

Comment: Ti version 1.7.5,
Runtime Error:
 Location: android_asset/Resources/ui.js;
 Message: Too deep recursion while parsing

Comment: Sounds like a Ti bug for Android.  Have you tried against an earlier version of Ti Mobile SDK to see if that works?

Comment: The sample that I downloaded from GitHub works but when I build and try to recreate the sample it does not on Android. I'm currently trying to check for the differences in the files and folders.

Answer (score -1):

You must use Google API SDK to use the geolocation on Android